# How to reverse map to an existing parent object using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }    // parent
    // ...
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }    // parent
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And the data transfer objects (DTOs):

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public AddressDto[] Addresses { get; set; }
    public OrderDto[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping (and flattening) from `Customer` to `CustomerDto` is easy. However, I'm having trouble reverse mapping from `CustomerDto` to `Customer`.

AutoMapper is not able to figure out the `Customer` property in `Address` or `Order`. It also can't figure out the `Address` property in `Order`.

I can make it work by first "ignoring" these properties by using the `Ignore` configuration method, and then using `AfterMap` to manually find the objects and assign them appropriately.

Is there a way for AutoMapper to do this automatically?

Comment: Have you solder the problem? please share the answer if you did, it may help others (including me ;)).

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I never solved the problem, and I ended up not using AutoMapper. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck!

Comment: Check this, I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011840/automap-a-property-to-property-of-sub-property?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I am trying to know how did I write *solder* instead of *solved* in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `.ReverseMap()` - http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

So given the following mappings:

```
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(expression =>
        {
            expression.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, obj => obj.MapFrom(customer => customer.Id))
                .ReverseMap();
            expression.CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, obj => obj.MapFrom(address => address.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.CustomerId, obj => obj.MapFrom(address => address.Customer.Id))
                .ReverseMap();
            expression.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, obj => obj.MapFrom(order => order.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.AddressId, obj => obj.MapFrom(order => order.Address.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.CustomerId, obj => obj.MapFrom(order => order.Customer.Id))
                .ReverseMap();
        }).CreateMapper();
```

And object:

```
        var customerTest = new Customer
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Addresses = new List<Address>
            {
                new Address
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Customer = new Customer{ Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
                }
            },
            Orders = new List<Order>
            {
                new Order
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Customer = new Customer{ Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
                    Address = new Address{ Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
                }
            }
        };
```

You could do the following:

```
        var resultDto = mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(customerTest);
        var resultModel = mapper.Map<Customer>(resultDto);
```

Comment: The `Customer` in `Address` and in `Order` should be the existing `customerTest`, not new objects. Also, the `Address` object in `Order` should be the one in the `Addresses` list, not a new object.