# AutoMap a property to property of sub-property

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have this simple data model:

```
// Model
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    .... Another values here ....
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    .... Another values here ....
}

// ViewModel
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map (using **AutoMapper**) the values of `PersonViewModel` to the corresponding properties (where AutoMapper discovers if the property should be in the root object or inside the sub-object). **Keeping in mind, AutoMapper should not create neither Person object nor Address** (the objects must be created manually to fill another properties before auto mapping), and AutoMapper uses the already existed objects. For example:

```
var addressObj = new Address
{

    ... Filling some values...

};
var personObj = new Person
{

    Address = addressObj;
    ... Filling some values...

};

mapper.Map(personViewModelObj, personObj); // How to make this work for both Person and Address properties?
```

How can I get that auto mapping to work for both person properties and address properties?

Should I add two mapping rules (for address and for person), and execute `mapper.Map()` twice?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.md

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47723564/2030565).

Comment: @Jasen, thank you, I am taking a look on that. Could you help me to understand this part, I cannot understand exactly what is the purpose of it: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blame/master/docs/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.md#L69

Comment: If your forward map doesn't map to the same properties as your reverse map. As the doc states _"For most cases you shouldn't need this, as the original MapFrom will be reversed for you. Use ForPath when the path to get and set the values are different."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Jasen comments I got it working. The main problem was that I am mapping in a reversed direction. This sentence in official documentation solves the problem:

> Unflattening is only configured for `ReverseMap`. If you want unflattening, you must configure `Entity` -> `Dto` then call `ReverseMap` to create an unflattening type map configuration from the `Dto` -> `Entity`.

Here is the link:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.md

In other words, to get unflattering to work, I have (or must) to map in this direction:

```
CreateMap<HierarchicalObject, FlattenedObject>()
    .ReverseMap();
```